# Por que o R não está encontrando a função criada

Tags: loop, r

Antes eu tinha feito um código extremamente grande para conseguir extrair os resultados que eu esperava, porém o código ficou bastante lento e com isso, eu estou tentando otimizá-lo:

Código anterior:

**Divisão por renda**

```
Sem_Rendimento<-filter(Renda, Renda[,2]=="Sem rendimento")
Sem_Rendimento_soma<-apply(Sem_Rendimento[,3:6],2,sum)
Res_Sem_Rendimento<-sum(Sem_Rendimento_soma)

Até_umquarto<-filter(Renda, Renda[,2]=="Até 1/4 de salário mínimo")
Até_umquarto_soma<-apply(Até_umquarto[1:27,3:6],c(2),sum)
Res_Até_umquarto<-sum(Até_umquarto_soma)

Entre_umquarto_ummeio<-filter(Renda, Renda[,2]=="Mais de 1/4 a 1/2 salário mínimo")
Entre_umquarto_ummeio_soma<-apply(Entre_umquarto_ummeio[1:27,3:6],c(2),sum)
Res_Entre_umquarto_ummeio<-sum(Entre_umquarto_ummeio_soma)

Entre_ummeio_um<-filter(Renda, Renda[,2]=="Mais de 1/2 a 1 salário mínimo")
Entre_ummeio_um_soma<-apply(Entre_ummeio_um[1:27,3:6],c(2),sum)
Res_Entre_ummeio_um<-sum(Entre_ummeio_um_soma)

Entre_um_dois<-filter(Renda, Renda[,2]=="Mais de 1 a 2 salários mínimos")
Entre_um_dois_soma<-apply(Entre_um_dois[1:27,3:6],c(2),sum)
Res_Entre_um_dois<-sum(Entre_um_dois_soma)

Entre_dois_três<-filter(Renda, Renda[,2]=="Mais de 2 a 3 salários mínimos")
Entre_dois_três_soma<-apply(Entre_dois_três[1:27,3:6],c(2),sum)
Res_Entre_dois_três<-sum(Entre_dois_três_soma)

Entre_tres_cinco<-filter(Renda, Renda[,2]=="Mais de 3 a 5 salários mínimos")
Entre_tres_cinco_soma<-apply(Entre_tres_cinco[1:27,3:6],c(2),sum)
Res_Entre_tres_cinco<-sum(Entre_tres_cinco_soma)

Entre_5_10<-filter(Renda, Renda[,2]=="Mais de 5 a 10 salários mínimos")
Entre_5_10_soma<-apply(Entre_5_10[1:27,3:6],c(2),sum)
Res_Entre_5_10<-sum(Entre_5_10_soma)

Entre_10_15<-filter(Renda, Renda[,2]=="Mais de 10 a 15 salários mínimos")
Entre_10_15_soma<-apply(Entre_10_15[1:27,3:6],c(2),sum)
Res_Entre_10_15<- sum(Entre_10_15_soma)
```

etc etc

**O código recente, que estou tentando é esse:**

```
renda<-NULL

Soma_renda<-NULL

resultado_renda<-NULL

for(h in 1:12)

 for(i in 1:length(Renda$Classes.de.rendimento.nominal.mensal))

  for(j in 1:length(Renda$Classes.de.rendimento.nominal.mensal))

   for(k in 1:12)

    {{{{
     renda(h)<- c(Renda[i,])

      i<-i+12

       Soma_renda(j)<-apply(renda(h)[1:27,3:6],c(2),sum)

        resultado_renda(k)<-sum(Soma_renda(j))

         Resultados_totais<- c(resultado_renda(k))
    }}}}
```

O problema, é que quando eu mando o código rodar, eu recebo essa mensagem do R:

> Error in renda(h) <- c(Renda[i, ]) : could not find function
>   "renda<-"

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: `renda(h)` implica que `renda` é uma função. Neste caso a função em causa é a função de atribuição `renda<-`. Mas a definição no código é `renda <- NULL`, isto é, `renda` é um vetor. Não será antes `renda[h]`?

Comment: E o mesmo pode ser dito de `Soma_renda(j)` e `resultado_renda(k)`. Aposto que é `Soma_renda[j]` e `resultado_renda[k]`.

Comment: Obrigado, eu fiz de uma outra maneira, criei uma function das funções que usei acima, e com isso fiz diminui o tamanho do programa.

Answer (score 1):

Porquê não se definiu nenhuma função. [Leia isso](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~statcur/Workshop2/Presentations/functions.pdf)

Comment: Já consegui, obrigado!